# Navigation from a nested div

Tags: jquery, html

In my website I've created a layout in which a `<div>` is a menu that lists some links ad a `<div>` that acts as main page in where every link opened is shown.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.linkpage').bind('click', function(e) {           
var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#main').load(url);
    e.preventDefault();
});

});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="menu">
<a href="Page1.php" class="linkpage">Page1</a>
<a href="Page2.php" class="linkpage">Page2</a>
</div>

<div id="main">
</div>

</body>
```

This is the colmplete page and opens link in the targeted div (main) when clicked. The problem happens when I click a link that is positioned in the main `<div>`:

```
<a href='Page2.php' class='linkpage'>ClickMe.</a>
```

This is not triggered in the same div, but it opens full page, like a `target='_top'`, instead opening itself in the same , maintaining the menu on the left of the page itself. What I've to add in the script to have the links opened in the proper target?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could speed up your selector by changing it to $('a.linkpage').  Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `.bind(` to `.live(` in your jQuery.

That way it will act on all links, even ones that are added to the DOM after the script has run.  The way it is right now, it will only act on links that are in the DOM at the time the script was run.

Comment: Thank you, now the links open properly in the div.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with one of my websites.  What you are asking for is to re-route all your links into that div, you don't want to just change the target, because if you just changed the target, it would still over write your page.

So you basically want to emulate the functionality of frames?  If that's correct, then you'll need to do something along the lines of catching every click and routing it back in (untested):

```
$('#main').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {   // use .on() if you have 1.7
    $('#main').load(this.href);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Yes, i want to emulate frames, using the divs, exactly as you described. I've tried the script but It doesn't work. Still, thank you ;)

Comment: Ah, that chunk of code above needs to be added to your existing one; not replace it.  Also, you would only need to use it if you didn't want to set all the links to class 'linkpage'